# Renaming Drawable Image in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

how do you rename an image on android studio. Do you right click the drawable folder and refactor - rename the image. Will it then update all the code to that new name??

Comment: Yes! That's the right way to do it.

Comment: also you can refactor resources in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you do a refactor, Android Studio changes all the usages of this resource.

Answer (score 0):

[Select Android project Structure and Right-click on image and select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Ny7.png)